# ¿Por qué me aparece este error?

Tags: python, class

Estoy intentando crear la clase Figura con sus respectivas funciones pero me dice que Figura no está definido. ¿Cuál es el error?

```
class Figura:

    def __init__(self):

        self._lados = None

    def main():

        triangulo = Figura()
        cuadrado = Figura()
        cuadrado._lados = 4
        triangulo._lados = 3
       
        print(f"El triángulo tiene {triangulo._lados} lados.")
        print(f"El cuadrado tiene {cuadrado._lados} lados.")
       
     if __name__ == '__main__':

        main()
```

ERROR => NameError: name 'Figura' is not defined

Comment: La identacion es correcta???

Comment: Como `main()` no tiene el parámetro `self` y la última línea es un llamado a `main()` a secas, entonces se deduce que `main()` es una función normal, o sea, no pertenece a la clase. Si indentas bien el código, funciona sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu programa esta mal indentado.

```
class Figura:

    def __init__(self):
        self._lados = None

def main():
    triangulo = Figura()
    cuadrado = Figura()
    cuadrado._lados = 4
    triangulo._lados = 3

    print(f"El triángulo tiene {triangulo._lados} lados.")
    print(f"El cuadrado tiene {cuadrado._lados} lados.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

La función `main()` no es parte de `class Figura:`, por lo que debe ir al mismo nivel por el margen izquierdo.

Comment: Si esta  mal indentado entonces sería un error tipografíco??